# How do I interact with a basic cmd program written in vb?

Tags: vb.net, nsis

Thanks for all the help so far. I was able to send the $Email variable to the stdio stream and receive it in the vb script. I am having a problem now with some of the code

```
Option Strict On

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

Module jrConnect

    Sub Main(ByVal cmdArgs() As String)
        Dim returnValue As Integer = 0
        ' See if there are any arguments.
        If cmdArgs.Length > 0 Then
            For argNum As Integer = 0 To UBound(cmdArgs, 1)

                Console.Write("your email address is " & cmdArgs(argNum))
                If cmdArgs(argNum) <> "" Then
                    Dim email As String = cmdArgs(argNum)
                    Console.Write("Your email is " & email)
                End If
             Next argNum
        End If
        Dim cs As String = "*********"
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(cs)
        Dim entID As String

        Try
            conn.Open()
            Dim stm As String = "SELECT ***** FROM **** WHERE email =" & "'" & email & "'"
            Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(stm, conn)
            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            While reader.Read()
                entID = reader.GetString(0)
            End While
            reader.Close()

            Dim stm2 = "SELECT ***** FROM ****** WHERE ***** = " & entID
            Dim cmd2 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(stm2, conn)
            Dim reader2 As MySqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
            Dim counter As Integer = 0

            While reader2.Read() And counter < 3
                Console.WriteLine(reader2.GetString(0) & "%")
                counter = counter + 1
            End While
            reader.Close()

        Catch ex As MySqlException
        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub

End Module
```

It will print the email address correctly but when it calls the email address in the sql statement it states that "email is not declared" Is it changing the value of it in the "Next argNum" command? It only writes the email to console once. Here is my NSIS script if necessary as well.

```
Outfile "test.exe"
Section
    SetOutPath $DOCUMENTS/
    Var /GLOBAL Email
    StrCpy $Email "spkelly8@gmail.com"

    nsExec::ExecToLog '"C:path/vbapp.exe" $Email'
    Pop $1
    Pop $2

    DetailPrint $1
    DetailPrint $2

SectionEnd
```

Comment: How are you invoking your app from your NSIS installer? (post the script).  I assume it all works fine running it manually from outside the installer?

Comment: im using the nsExec command and yes it runs fine outside the installer
nsExec::ExecToLog '"C:\path\dbConnect.exe" email@gmail.com'

Comment: nsExec uses pipes for stdin/out I'm guessing but I don't think stdin has any data for you to read...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the NSIS manual:

```
nsExec will execute command-line based programs and capture the output
without opening a dos box
```

Your `console.Readline` will expect some kind of interation and since its not connected to stdin/stdout, will fail.  Since you dont want the DOS box, and you want to send the email string via stdin rather than enter it manually, use `ExecDos::exec`

```
ExecDos::exec /TIMEOUT=2000 "$DOCUMENTS\VBApp.exe" "$Email$\n"
```

Note the `$` in front of `\n` for NSIS to send a literal new line rather than the string `\n`

Comment: I need to send the contents of $Email variable to the program without opening the command window. How would i be able to send it as a parameter

Comment: @spkelly86 Please update your question and include your NSIS script.  Not knowing the full details causes people to post incorrect answers to your question as we are not really sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks for the help. gave it a shot, still not receiving the argument. Have a feeling it has something to do with the VB script. Added a picture of where i am at so far

Comment: I changed the argument thing back to a console.readline still nothing passed :(

Comment: Add `/DETAILED` to the call to `ExecDos::exec`, it will then display any output in the detail pain of the installer so you can debug and see how far its getting.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read from stdin but nsExec does not provide any data you can read from stdin. Change the VB program to parse the commandline instead or use [ExecDos](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecDos_plug-in) or [ExecCmd](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecCmd_plug-in) if your child process has to get the data from stdin...

Comment: I tried the ExecDos plugin, but it will not allow me to send $Email to the command line

Comment: And you used ExecDos::exec "$instdir\App.exe" "foo@bar.com$\n" "" ?

Comment: yea i tried ExecDos::exec "C:\path\VBapp.exe" "$Email$\n" "" its returning 0 and not returning any of the Console.Writes i added to see if it even executed properly